# How to use a HTML range input type for cherrypy script?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cherrypy

I am trying to use range a slider in order to trigger an action on a cherrypy script. 
I want it to change the action according to the position of the slider.
I am a complete javascript noob but I tried this way and it doesn't work.

```
     function onSelectedOption(sel) {
             if ((sel.selectedIndex) == 1) {
             document.getElementById("edit").action =
             "doSomething";
                 document.getElementById("edit").submit();
        }


<form method="link" action="">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" name="edit" id="edit" method="GET">
```

Comment: The `action` and `method` attributes should be used for the `<form>` element, not `<input>`. If you want to submit the form after changing `range` value, add an event listener like this: http://codepen.io/helb/pen/KWEgKQ

Comment: How do i set different action for the different values of the range?

Comment: `if(range.value === "3") {form.action = "doSomething"} else if(range.value === "4") {form.action = "doSomethingElse"}`

Comment: You can also do API calls directly from Javascript instead of sending the form: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch